# Not setting NSError to nil yields crash

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm experiencing a very weird issue, which after several months of testing just happened to pop up as I was about to submit the app.

I have the folliwing method which takes some JSON data and converts it to a dictionary:

```
NSError *e;
NSMutableDictionary *result= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData 
                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
if (e != nil) return nil;
```

For the past few months, this method has been used non stop, with absolutely no problems. But just today, it just stopped working. It now always results in an error (with no description; just a non-nill error).

It turns out, all I had to do to fix the problem was set `NSError *e = nil;`. I thought it was just good practice to do that, not absolutely critical. This scares me. I wonder how many times else I'm doing this in my code. Can anyone explain what could possibly be going on?

Also, I am using ARC, which I guess makes it even stranger that this is happening.

Comment: e is a local variable which is not automatically initialized upon creation. It may well be that it happened to be zero and after your app evovled it got some diffeerent random value. In cases where e is a property, not a local var, then it should be nil'ed without you doing anything. Later, wen JSONObjectWithData is called and no error happened, e is not touched at all and remains with its initial "value". That's bascially it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is wrong, and so is your fix. What you need to do is say

```
if (result == nil) {
    // an error occurred, and the NSError* variable can now be consulted
}
```

If `result` is anything besides `nil`, then you're not allowed to assume *anything* about the contents of `e`.

---

The basic reason here is that APIs that have `NSError**` return values are not required to put anything in that spot unless the API returned an error. Typically this means that in the non-error case they don't modify the value at all, so whatever you had in your `e` variable before is what you have after. If your code is compiled without ARC, your `e` variable will have garbage from the stack in it. Under ARC it will be initialized to `nil`, but I'm guessing you're not under ARC for reasons I will get to.

However, it's more complicated than this. Even if the method does not return an error, it may still have modified the `NSError**` value anyway. The simple example is if this method calls another method, passing the same `NSError**` into that method, and then recovers from the error and returns a success value instead. Yet the second method may have populated your `NSError*` variable with an error that is no longer valid.

Now, the reason why I think your code isn't ARC is because, to the best of my knowledge, all of the Cocoa APIs these days take pains to *not* modify the `NSError**` value unless an error occurred. This is in line with the new guidelines established a year or two ago (it was either at the beginning of 2011 or 2012, I forget which) that say that methods that have an `NSError**` parameter should only modify it in the error case. This is intended to allow code that says `NSError *e = nil; [foo callAPIWithError:e]; if (e) ...` to work, even though that's not actually following the rules of `NSError` APIs, purely as a practical matter to be more resilient in the face of incorrect code. And since ARC nils out all automatic variables with an object type, your crash suggests that `e` was not nilled out and therefore you're not in ARC.

However, despite what I just said in the above paragraph, you still should not assume that any `NSError`-enabled API will leave the `NSError` value alone when no error is thrown. The current guidelines for implementing such APIs do say that should be true, but that's not a hard requirement. Any code written before those guidelines may not behave that way, and any code written after the guidelines may just ignore them. The rules for calling an `NSError`-enabled API continue to state that the return value of the API must be consulted, and the `NSError*` variable may only be observed if the return value indicated an error occurred.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Oddly, I am using ARC though. The weird thing is is that this method never raised any problems before, only today did it start, and the only thing I changed today was adding HockeyApp (beta testing/crash reporting), but I'm not sure how that would affect this method.

Comment: @mohabitar: That is curious. I wonder if the compiler is doing any sort of fancy analysis and deciding that, since the `NSError*`'s very first use is in an out-param of type `NSError * __autoreleasing *`, then the variable itself should be of type `__autoreleasing` instead of `__strong`, which eliminates the initial `nil` assignment. That surprises me, but it's theoretically possible.

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain step by step the reason of an error:

```
NSError *e; //some garbage non-nil value may be here

NSMutableDictionary *result= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData 
                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e]; // no error, e is untouched, garbage is still here

if (e != nil) return nil; // there was no error but because of garbage we think there was one
```

So first you need to check the result value or set e variable to nil (the first one is preferred).

Comment: This is incorrect. You must first check if `result` is `nil` before it is safe to check `error`. You are also simply repeating the original code being asked about.

Comment: @rmaddy I didn't tell this was a correct way. I just explained the reason of an error step by step.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very clear. You posted code. This made it appear like it was supposed to be the correct code.

Comment: Max is right. He provided an answer to the question wich was asking "why is that so?" and not "how to do it better?". As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

The [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData%3aoptions%3aerror%3a) for that method says:

> **Return Value**
>   A Foundation object from the JSON data in data, or nil if an error occurs.

So use the return value to detect the error, and only if you want detail look at the error object.